# Condition to bring data dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has ID, Name and DateOfService columns. I have to use a condition in my query which will give data dynamically from the beginning of this year till june, then next month from the beginning of the year till july, then august.....I cannot use a stored procedure for this.

I am unable to figure out what date function to use to get data dynamically. I am able to hard-code just for the month of june or july...

SQL query I used:

```
Select ID, Name, DateOfService from dbo.tableA
where Month(DateOfService) ='06' and Year(DateOfService)='2016'
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: We need a lot more information to help here. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can you clarify what date range you want to filter on? What does "get data dynamically" mean? For example, do you mean something like "from the beginning of the current year to **now** (current date)"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its from the beginning of the year till june.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its from the beginning of the year(january 2016) to June of 2016.

Answer (score 1):

simply compare year with MONTH less than current month:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @Table
WHERE
    YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH(DateColumn) < MONTH(GETDATE())
```

OR SQL-Server 2012 using `EOMONTH`

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @Table
WHERE
    YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND DateColumn <= EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
```

OR SQL-Server 2008

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @Table
WHERE
    YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND DateColumn <= DATEADD(DAY,- DAY(GETDATE()),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Generate Some Test Data:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),Value INT, DateColumn DATE)
DECLARE @D DATE = '2015/12/01'
WHILE @D <= GETDATE()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Table (Value,DateColumn)
    VALUES (DAY(@D)%8,@D)
    SET @D = DATEADD(DAY,1,@D)
END
```

Comment: I tried using  SELECT *
FROM
    @Table
WHERE
    YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND DateColumn <= DATEADD(DAY,- DAY(GETDATE()),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) but still it gives me all the months data, not just June.

Comment: @Shra I thought you wanted all dates from the year up to the month before.  If you only want that month just change <= to =.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Sorry for the confusion. Its from the beginning of the year till june.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to parse individual elements of a DATETIME value. For example if `@MyValue='01/02/03 04:05:06:07 PM'` then `DATEPART(SECOND,@MyDateValue)` would return 6.